# Digital guitar effect / DSP

Tags: microcontroller, dsp

I have to design and create a MCU device as a project for my university. I would like to create a real-time digital guitar effect, which should have a decent sound quality. I don't have any real experience in such projects, however I'm familliar with theoretical basics of eletronics and microcontrollers.

The device should have a mono jack input and a (maybe stereo) jack output. To the jack input goes a signal from electric guitar and output goes to a guitar power amp (which I own). Probably also a LCD display, a few switches and pots and maybe other I/O.

I'm not sure about the inside of the device - at first I thought that I need a AD converter at the input to connect it to the MCU and then DA converter at the output to output processed guitar signal. Then I read something about DSP microcontrollers, which probably have AD and DA integrated.

How can I build a digital guitar effect? What part should I buy? My requirements:

- a good sound quality - device should be useful on stage or at studio
- it should be as easy to program and build - it's my first project
- parts should be available on the market (Europe/Poland)
- parts should be reasonably cheap - I don't want it be more expensive than digital guitar effects available on market and there's always a possibility that something goes wrong and I would have to buy parts again

Answer (score 3):

> a good sound quality - device should be useful on stage or at studio

Quality isn't a spec.

> it should be as easy to program and build - it's my first project

The algorithms to do anything meaningful or interesting are not easy to implement.

> parts should be available on the market (Europe/Poland)

That is the one bullet point that is doable here.

> parts should be reasonably cheap - I don't want it be more expensive than digital
>   guitar effects available on market and there's always a possibility
>   that something goes wrong and I would have to buy parts again

Building prototypes is **always** more expensive than production. It's going to be pretty much impossible to get your cost below that of an existing product that has been optimized for production.

tl;dr This is far too ambitious for a first project, let alone a university project with time constraints. Pick something simpler.

Comment: Well, algorithms are another thing - that's not what I meant by "easy to program". I thought about ease-to-use IDE and available libraries.

Comment: @Rames The algorithms will be 90% of this project.

Comment: I'm completely fine with that. I believe that I have enough expirience in programming to overcome algorithmic difficulties. I'm concerned about the costs and not sure what is the best hardware for my purpose.